# How to divide my output to individual youtube url's and put to the list in python3?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want make simple youtube channel's scraper from other website to create list of contacts made of links from  which is located on youtube site.

Used libs: beautifulsoup and requests.

I got some problems in extracting only url's as single object and putting it to the list.

It's my first program after "hello world" on python so I am still a newbie.

I have no idea what should I do next

```py
#----------------------------------------------------
#Libs
#----------------------------------------------------
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#----------------------------------------------------
#variables
#----------------------------------------------------
page = ('http://ranking.vstars.pl/?side=96&&sort=month_change')

#----------------------------------------------------                 
#functions
#----------------------------------------------------
def scraper():

    x=0

    target = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(target.text, 'html.parser')

    for links in soup.find_all("td", "a", class_= "href"):
        print(links, '\n')
        x += 1

    print ("Number of links:" , x)

#----------------------------------------------------  
#codes
#----------------------------------------------------
scraper()
```

```py
Output:

<td class="href"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq-EgxhHVTFWVZcjFwsfnWA" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">YouTube</a></td> 

...

<td class="href"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpcG5MwAks-At2L-gbSppag" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">YouTube</a></td> 

Number of links: 81
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you please provide it?

Comment: list =[https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq-EgxhHVTFWVZcjFwsfnWA,  ... , https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpcG5MwAks-At2L-gbSppag] After that I want make other function which will call every link from list and then extract data from <div id="links-holder"> which is located on that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted an output of type List, I took the liberty of storing it in a list:

#### Code

```py
#----------------------------------------------------
#Libs
#----------------------------------------------------
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#----------------------------------------------------
#variables
#----------------------------------------------------
page = ('http://ranking.vstars.pl/?side=96&&sort=month_change')

#----------------------------------------------------
#functions
#----------------------------------------------------
def scraper():

    x=0

    target = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(target.text, 'html.parser')

    all_links = []
    for links in soup.find_all("td", "a", class_= "href"):
        all_links.append(links.contents[0].attrs['href'])
        x += 1

    print(all_links)
    print ("Number of links:" , x)

#----------------------------------------------------
#codes
#----------------------------------------------------
scraper()
```

#### Output

> [u'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCq-EgxhHVTFWVZcjFwsfnWA', u'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPf-3giVvdU55kIBN2CbLRQ', ... ]
>
> ('Number of links:', 81)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function:

```
def scraper():
    x=0
    target = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(target.text, 'html.parser')

    for td in soup.find_all("td", class_= "href"):
        for links in td.find_all("a"):
            print(links['href'], '\n')
            x += 1

    print ("Number of links:" , x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getLinks(url):
   x = 0
   html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
   links = []

   for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
      links.append(link.get('href'))
      x = x + 1

     print(links,x)

return links

getLinks("http://google.com")
```